# Configure the service angular-lazy-img with a dynamic scrollable container generated on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, lazy-loading, provider

As a new developer on angularjs I have a specific question regarding provider. I'm trying to use the lazy load  [angular-lazy-load](https://github.com/Pentiado/angular-lazy-img) that has a specific functionality regarding the scrollable container. This scrollable container should be set in the config step.
Here is an example :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularLazyImg']);
myApp.config(['lazyImgConfigProvider',
  function(lazyImgConfigProvider) {
   var scrollable = document.querySelector('.container');
    lazyImgConfigProvider.setOptions({
      offset: 1, // how early you want to load image (default = 100)
      errorClass: 'error', // in case of loading image failure what class should be added (default = null)
      successClass: null, // in case of loading image success what class should be added (default = null)
      onError: function(image) {}, // function fired on loading error
      onSuccess: function(image) {}, // function fired on loading success
      container: angular.element(scrollable)
    });
  }
]);

myApp.controller('lazyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.images = [{
      url: "https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a"
    }, {
      url: "http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg"
    }, {
      url: "http://sourcingrecruitment.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/stackoverflow.png"
    }, {
      url: "http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png"
    }, {
      url: "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/stackoverflow-3-xxl.png"
    }, {
      url: "https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/139426?v=3&s=400"
    }, {
      url: "http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png"
    } ];
  }
]);
```

```css
.container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-guide-concepts-1-production</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/Pentiado/angular-lazy-img/master/release/angular-lazy-img.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  Test lazy image
  <div ng-controller="lazyCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div ng-repeat="image in images">
        <img width="100px" height="100px" lazy-img="{{image.url}}" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

But my question is how can I do to add a container option if the container element  is not yet created and will be by the controller ?

Thanks in advance, please let me know which informations are missing to answer.

Comment: I found the issue 4 on github that could help, I will try to add attribut lazyImgContainer to my container https://github.com/Pentiado/angular-lazy-img/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the trick is to add an attribut lazyImgContainer to the container in the html file. Not yet documented in github so I have added a pull request to get it documented.